# Python, окружение, модули

Tags: python, модули, virtualenv, python-import

Захожу в разных ssh сессиях на удаленную машину для выполнения скрипта .py. В скрипте ипортируется и используется numpy. В одной сессии он не импортируется (отсутствует такой модуль в окружении), в другой сессии все норм. Один и тот же юзер.
Окружение не активно в обоих случаях (VIRTUAL_ENV дает ошибку ключа в os.environ)

`sys.executable` дает один и тот же путь при обоих вызовах '/usr/bin/python'.
`sys.path` дает почти одинаковые пути за исключением одного (по непонятной причине...):
неработающий вариант [--||--||--, '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', --||--||--], то есть все те же самые пути что и в работающей сессии но плюс один путь.
При этом в help("modules") у неработающего варианта действительно нет numpy, у работающего есть. Я вообще не понимаю что происходит...